# Doing email analysis for a postmortem (Exchange or IMAP)

Tags: email, outlook, imap, analysis

I ended up doing some emergency PM stuff at work and I would like to post mortem my email to see who I was talking to and what I did wrong. I'm looking for suggestions on tools that would allow me to see the amount of email I was sending/receiving and perhaps see various statistics etc. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Outlook, try [Xobni](http://www.xobni.com/) which provides email statistics on a per-user basis.